# How do I build an xcode project for the itunes store?

Tags: iphone, xcode, binary, itunes, executable

I've got my apps running on my iphone, great, however to list on the itunes store I need the "universal binary" thing.

I've tried finding answers, but I can't seem to find a concise useable explanation to doing this in xcode.  I always get errors when I try to build a binary.  Can anyone point me towards a basic step-by-step procedure I can follow to creating a universal executable binary which can be uploaded on the itunes store?

One more thing, is there some type of app, like the rename project app, or applescript thing, that can do this for me with a few clicks?

Comment: A Universal Binary is a binary that will run on both the Intel and PowerPC architectures. There's only one architecture for the iPhone (ARM), so you've got the wrong terminology! As people have said, the Apple Developer documentation has a good guide on doing this, http://developer.apple.com/iphone/ - search for "distribution"

Comment: Generally speaking I think this is a good question, because Apple doesn't make it very clear about what targets, certificates, etc. are needed for the app store upload.

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

**Prepare a new provisioning profile for App Store**

1. Make sure you have Ad Hoc distribution working OK.
2. Go onto the Program Portal > Provisioning > Distribution
3. New Profile button
4. Distribution Method: App Store
5. Profile Name: MyApp App Store  (or whatever)
6. App ID: MyApp  (you have already created one right?)
7. Submit button

**Set up the new profile/configuration in XCode**

8. Download the certificate (you can click on the Distribution tab to reload that tab while it's being generated) and load it into XCode
9. In XCode, open your project and go to Project > Edit Project Settings (or double-click on the first item under Groups & Files panel)
10. Configurations tab, click on your existing Ad Hoc distribution configuration, that already works, and click Duplicate button. Call the new one "App Store"
11. Click on Build tab, then under Code Signing > Code Signing Entity in the popup choose "iPhone Distribution - MyCompanyName" under "MyApp App Store"

**Build & Upload to iTunes Connect**

12. Clean all for good luck, then set Active Configuration to "App Store", build & go. Test it on your iPhone.
13. Find your built app in the Finder, in your project directory > build > App Store-iphoneos > MyApp.app ... right click and "Compress MyApp.app"
14. Upload resulting MyApp.zip to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Sadly, with Xcode 4.5.x, this DOES NOT WORK any more - Apple has deliberately disabled the above. If you do the "compress" step, it compresses the wrong build. Apple WILL NOT ALLOW YOU to make an app store build any more.

Answer (score 5):

A Universal Binary has nothing to do with it. To distribute through the App Store, you need to create a Distribution provisioning profile. The iPhone developer portal has step-by-step directions for this. look under the "Distribution" tab.

Comment: ok I'll look again..., from what I remember this is the only thing I was having trouble understanding/implementing....I wonder, why couldn't there just be a "build for appstore" executable function or whatever that would accomplish this in a step or two.. ok, now I'm off to the apple site.. If anyone else can add anything...

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions listed by *sbwoodside* but had problems with the last part (Build & Upload to iTunes Connect). I realized that the built version didn't run on the device. This is what worked for me:

**Build & Upload to iTunes Connect**

- Clean all for good luck.
- Go to "Edit Scheme" and in the Archive menu, select the App Store
  build configuration.
- Select iOS Device or a specific device in the drop down menu and go
  to Product->Archive.
- Once Xcode is done archiving, it will open the organizer window and
  show the archives section. Select the last archive and click
  "Submit".
- You will be asked to enter your distribution certificate. Select
  the one created for the App Store.
- XCode will upload the app to iTunes Connect without the need of
  using Application Loader. For this to work, the app has to be in
  "Ready to Upload" status in iTunes Connect.

You won't get to test the last version with the device. Therefore it's best to make an ad hoc version before to be able to test all features and once everything is working, duplicate the ad hoc configuration for the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your provisioning profiles downloaded and installed you need to make some changes within XCode to get the app to work on your iPhone and eventually to submit to the iTunes store. You'll also need to add an Entitlemests.plist object to your project. You also need to tweak your build profile and your info.plist to point to your application name.

But as Mark B already said, just got through the developer portal and follow those instructions. Just make sure your define the right provisioning profile for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks Ohiodude..I've just got to learn to follow step-by-step instructions...somewhat difficult for a spaz like me! I'll get this working soon hopefully..