# xcode 4 wont submit my application?

Tags: submit, xcode4

Hi guys i am trying to submit my application to the app store but xcode 4 won't finish submitting the application . i get to the point where i select the app details that i made in itunes connect. then when i hit submit the loading bar appears then disappears. i'v checked my code Signing identities and they all seam to be right anyone now whats going on or another way besides xcode to archive my app for App Loader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since XCode 4 is only in Beta stadium, you cannot submit any apps to the app store yet (as stated on the download page at http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/).

In order to submit your app to the app store, the submission process has to be started using XCode 3.2. Since the code is built on the same framework, there should not be any problems opening it in XCode 3.2 (never tried it myself though).

Comment: I'm sorry I never used Xcode 4 because I don't really like it so I use Xcode 3.2 but since that's cleared up how could I use Xcode 3.2 to get my binary to upload ? Thanks

Comment: I thought you are using Xcode 4 (as stated in your question). If you need further information on how to provision your app to the app store, consider reading up on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803683/how-do-i-build-an-xcode-project-for-the-itunes-store-please-help) or on ITunes [here](https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.1579102445.01579102451.1580085281?i=2050284209).