# app store binary: the executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios

I'm about to build my first ipad application. I followed the steps listed here for creating the binary: [How do I build an xcode project for the itunes store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803683/how-do-i-build-an-xcode-project-for-the-itunes-store) (see first answer).

Unluckily, I get the already mentioned alert when trying to build on my ipad. I can build with the simulator, though, without any problem. Is it possible to make an app store build with an app store distribution profile on an ipad? When I select the distribution profile on the organizer, I read the text: This profile cannot be installed on devices.

Sorry if this is a question that has been asked before. I searched on stackoverflow and on the internet and couldn't find any answer. By the way, I had created an ad hoc distribution and that worked perfectly on the ipad. I don't have any Entitlements.plist since I didn't need it for the ad hoc distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two provisioning profiles. The development one is for putting your app on devices for testing. The distribution is for submitting your application to iTunesConnect.

You have to swap between the two provisioning profiles when you want swap between putting the app on the device and the store. Consider creating [targets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) to achieve this.

Comment: I do have three provisioning profiles for that app: one for developing, one for the ad hoc distribution, and one for the app store distribution. I selected the app store distribution profile by clicking on Edit Scheme -> Run -> Build Configuration. In the Build Settings I made sure that the App Store Configuration is using the right profile. Is there a better way to achieve this with xcode 4?

Comment: You're doing the right thing to prepare your app for the store. But to put it on your device, you need to use the development profile, you have to change back to the development profile. You should be able to manage this more easily by using different targets. Check the link that I put in my original answer.